# Solve equation with 2 unknowns

Tags: r, solver

How can I get an output that gives me a range of PDs (probability of default) and LGDs (loss given default) between 0 and 1 that solves the following equation.

With these constants:

```
Correlation <- .15
MaturityAdjusted <- .1
WAL <- 7
```

This is the equation to be solved:

```
(LGD*pnorm((1-Correlation)^-0.5*qnorm(PD)+(Correlation/(1-Correlation))^0.5*qnorm(0.999))-PD*LGD)*(1-1.5*MaturityAdjusted)^-1*(1+(WAL-2.5)*MaturityAdjusted)
```

Assume:

```
PD <- .01
LGD <- .1
```

Then the formula gives

```
0.01710399
```

What I would like to have is an output that gives me a range of PDs and LGDs which also produces 0.01710399.

For example a higher PD and lower LGD would give the same result.